# ¿Porque no ejecuta los eventos OnBeforeUnistall y OnAfterInstall? C#

Tags: c#

tengo un problema, lo que estoy intentando hacer es que cuando el software se instale escriba unas keys en el Registry key del sistema y cuando se desinstale las borre, pero el problema es que no esta entrando a los eventos de la clase Install

```
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class Installer1 : Installer
{
    Log Log = Log.ObtenerInstancia();
    public Installer1() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            rkApp.SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
            base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Escribir(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnBeforeUninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            rkApp.DeleteSubKey(Application.ProductName);
            base.OnBeforeUninstall(savedState);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Escribir(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Se necesita hacer algun procedimiento mas para que funcionen los eventos?? de echo visual me indica que no hay ninguna referencia hacia los metodos

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la porción de código donde llamas al método Install? Ya que supuestamente una vez iniciado desencadenaría los eventos pertinentes.